# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_registration_enabled() on WooCommerce form-checkout.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a plugin where I need checkout form. I am getting below error when I include `form-checkout.php`

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_registration_enabled() on null in C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-content\plugins\wooinstant\inc\templates\checkout\form-checkout.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-content\plugins\wooinstant\inc\wooinstant-layout.php(19): include() #1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): wooinstant_layout('') #2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\general-template.php(2630): do_action('wp_footer') #5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\footer.php(44): wp_footer() #6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\template.php(688): require_once('C:\xampp7\htdoc...') #7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\template.php(647): load_template('C:\xampp7\htdoc...', true) #8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-includes\general-template.php(76): locate_template(Array, true) #9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-con in C:\xampp7\htdocs\woo\wp-content\plugins\wooinstant\inc\templates\checkout\form-checkout.php on line 28

[image: Error]

I want to include checkout form file like this

```
include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php';
```

[image]

I don't want to use `[woocommerce_checkout]` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using `$checkout = WC()->checkout();`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating the WooCommerce plugin will remove your code in furture. Instead of that you can try **wc_get_template_part** function to include the checkout

Comment: I copied the file and paste on my plugin template folder. it is not directly linked with woocommerce plugin template.

Comment: Even you can use the same code in your plugin to secure any outdated template message from WooCommerce